# Prove $X$ and $Y$ are not independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Their joint probability density function is

$$f: (x, y) \mapsto C(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y} \mathbf{1}_A(x, y)$$

where $C \in \mathbb{R}$, $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}, |x| < y \land y > 0\}$

and $\mathbf{1}_A: (x,y) \mapsto 1$ if $(x,y) \in A$ else $0$

How can you prove that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

**EDIT**

We need to prove that $f \neq f_X f_Y$ where

$$f_X = \int_y C(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y}\mathbf{1}_A(x, y)dy$$

$$f_Y = \int_x C(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y}\mathbf{1}_A(x, y)dx$$

How can I prove that?

Comment: Observe that we cannot write $f=f_Xf_Y$ where $f_X$, $f_Y$ are the marginal densities of $X$, $Y$.

Comment: $f_X = \int_y C(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y}\mathbf{1}_A(x, y)dy$, I don't know how to deal with the $\mathbf{1}_A(x,y)$ because it needs to stay but I don't know how to make it depend only on $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the joint density, we have
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\mathbb R^2} f&=\int_0^\infty\int_{-y}^y C(y^2-x^2)e^{-y}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= C\int_0^\infty \frac43 y^3 e^{-y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= 8C,
\end{align}
so $C=\frac18$. To compute the marginal densities, we integrate the joint density. For $x>0$,
$$
f_X(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac18 (y^2-x^2)e^{-y}\ \mathsf dy = \frac14 e^{-x}(1+x),
$$
and for $x<0$,
$$
f_X(x) = \int_{-x}^\infty \frac18 (y^2-x^2)e^{-y}\ \mathsf dy = \frac14 e^{x}(1-x),
$$
so
$$f_X(x) = \frac14 e^x(1-x)\mathsf 1_{(-\infty,0]}(x) + \frac14 e^{-x}(1+x)\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}. $$
For $y>0$ we have
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{-y}^y \frac18(y^2-x^2)e^{-y}\ \mathsf dx = \frac16 y^3 e^{-y}. $$
It is clear that $f\ne f_Xf_Y$, so $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.